# How to specify port number with "hg clone"

Tags: mercurial, ssh

I'm trying to use `hg clone ssh://user@ip:/path/to/repo .` but I need to specify a port number.  I've tried including a `-p` after `hg clone` but that gets me nowhere.  I've done this before but can't remember :-\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax (from `hg help urls`, as referred to from `hg help clone`) is:

```
ssh://[user@]host[:port]/[path][#revision]
```

Thus, between the `:` and the `/` you should be putting your port number.